# My android app is getting device not supported when trying to download with tablet

Tags: java, android, device, tablet

I have an android app on the market called [D Bitly](http://bit.ly/mz6DIB) and I have a tablet user trying to download it and is getting "device not supported". I have double checked the market settings and it says that all devices are supported.

I have done a quick google search and I am not coming up with anything.

It requires 2 permissions:

android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

and is for android 2.2 and up.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

**Edit:** for those of you looking for an exact answer. The problem was being caused by copy protection. I have implemented the licensing service and removed the copy protection and all seems to be okay. Not exactly sure why copy protection doesn't play nicely with tablets or newer OS...

Comment: Do you know which tablet it is? (Make/model)

Comment: The copy protection causes a lot of problems. It is good practice to go with the Licensing Service instead. It also causes trouble for paid apps in very unique and random situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is available for download for the XOOM and Galaxy Tab, so it's not a tablet-specific issue.

It's possible that the user in question has a modded ROM or something, perhaps causing some confusion with the Market servers. Beyond that, it may just be something peculiar with that Dell model.

Comment: Thank you so much for testing this! I ran it on the emulator because I don't have a tablet yet myself to test on. This makes me feel so much better.

Comment: Here is my take, I think it had something to do with copy protection. It's a free app so I guess it really doesn't need it. I would be willing to bet that if I turned it back on tablets would have issues with downloading. I haven't looked to see if there are any documented cases that support that but... Thank again for testing it.