# Android app is getting device not supported when trying to download with tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I have an android app on google play called IronGrudge and lately (after latest release) I have tablet users writing me that they are getting "device not supported".

I really can't figure out why.

The question relates to this question:
[My android app is getting device not supported when trying to download with tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336254/my-android-app-is-getting-device-not-supported-when-trying-to-download-with-tabl)
but the solution isn't valid for me as I haven't used any copy-protection (that I know of).

**Further information:**

My app really isn't that restrictive when it comes to supported devices:

- 3080 Supported devices, 0 Excluded devices.
- Require Android version 2.2 or higher.
- Free.

In the latest version I have 2 new permissions (the only two in the app):

- modify/delete USB storage contents
- test access to protected storage

  (in the AndroidManifest.xml file the permission(s) looks like this:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  ```

Logically the problem should relate to the two new permissions, I just can't figure out how it relates, how these permissions causes problems.

The tablets in question (the ones I've heard about):

- Galaxy Tab 10.1
- Samsung Tablet gt-p5110 (android 4.0.4)
- Samsung Tablet gt-p7500 (android 4.0.4)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="wagnerbang.irongrudge"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="@string/versionName">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"

        android:backupAgent=".DbBackupAgent"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
            android:value="BLA BLA BLA BLA" /> 

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SplashActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".LegalInfoActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />        
        <activity android:name=".BattleListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BattleViewActivity" android:theme="@style/DialogNoTitle" />        
        <activity android:name=".BattleCreateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FactionListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".CasterListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".PlayerListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    <activity android:name=".PlayerCreateActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />        
        <activity android:name=".ScenarioListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".ScenarioCreateActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />        
        <activity android:name=".EventListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".EventCreateActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />        
        <activity android:name=".ResultActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />   
        <activity android:name=".StatisticsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchFilterCreateActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".QueryTypeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />               
        <activity android:name=".BattleListLandscapePref" />
        <activity android:name=".BattleListPortraitPref" />
        <activity android:name=".BattleListOrderingPref" />
        <activity android:name=".BackupActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".BackupLogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchFilterListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: So what you get in answer>